# Javascript-Generated Submit Button Not POSTing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, firefox

I have seen similar posts related to this question but none have proven useful.

I have a several javascript-generated submit buttons for a form.

PHP sets certain parameters for functions depending on which button is pushed. **The problem is that the submit buttons do not get added to the POST array AT ALL if they are generated by javascript;** If I put submit buttons directly into the view they work just fine. **This is only a problem in Firefox**

NOTE: this is not a problem with the form actually submitting - just that the name=>value of the submit button is not being passed to POST.

```
$('#my-total-dial').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: myTotalRecords,
        title: {
          text: 'All Time'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'All',
        data: [myTotalRecords],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:18px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/></div>' +
                   '<button name="my-total-records-view" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" title="View Records"></button><button name="my-total-records-csv" class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" title="Export Records to Spreadsheet"></button>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' records'
        }
    }]

}));
```

In Chrome, this is what is spit out by POST:

```
array(3) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "XB16S144KnTue3ER6x4H8mdQO1rwxGP6BmAciYvK" ["my-total-records-view"]=> string(6) "Submit" ["user_name"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

And this is what I get in Firefox

```
array(2) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "UTKWISXMNvUfGjfFxxya8ojYXSgGc8dS5kUS5Hck" ["user_name"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: Do you mean that the buttons don't submit the form, or that they do submit the form but the button value itself isn't part of the POST data? Because your buttons don't have a value specified or any displayed text, so what value are you expecting?

Comment: Right, the POST should at least show the key of, for example, ['my-total-records-view'] and have an empty string as its value. In Firefox, however, it doesn't even add the key to the POST array.

Comment: Try specifying a value (which you can then ignore in your server-side code if all you need is to check for existence of the key).

Answer (score 1):

By default `<button>` elements does not submit the form. Use `<input type='submit'>` instead.

Comment: or add an onclick="doSomething()" method to the <button>

Comment: @Ravioli87 make sure you actually append this buttons to a form. if not, use the `onclick` to submit manually.

Comment: By default `<button>` elements _do_ submit a form. Assuming they are actually in a form. If the `type` attribute is not specified it defaults to `type="submit"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn not in every browser, that's probably why it doesn't work in ff for him. From w3s: `Note: If you use the <button> element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use <input> to create buttons in an HTML form.`

Comment: But the note you quote doesn't say they won't submit the form, it just cautions about what value might be submitted for the button (older IE submitted the wrong value in some circumstances).

Comment: The problem is that NO value is being submitted to the POST array for the submit button. In Chrome and IE, I see ['my-total-records-view'] => String(0)"". The form itself submits just fine.